# Case Sensitive URL's - Can this be avoided?

Tags: url, iis, expressionengine, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

First off, I know this is somewhat of a "dead horse", but I have trolled the internet and SO for a solution and found none. Unfortunately, this correct answer may be no answer.

I have a site in expressionengine that is running on IIS7, (don't ask), and running Structure.

There is a common problem of content editors either creating or changing entries and wanting to modify the URL. When they do this, they tend to get case sensitivity crazy and either camel case or just design their own method of casing to the modified URLs.

### Round 1

The first issue I had was the marketing team placing camel cased and oddly cased URLs in links of marketing emails, etc. This was remedied by catching and rewriting the URLs in the .htaccess file like:

```
#Make URL's lower case
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

That did the trick with the URL issues for round 1.

### Round 2

The next issue was two fold. --> FF to the point.

Fold 1: They have internal development that runs IIS .Net apps which were in camel cased format. The change almost shut them down for one morning. (Oops!)

Fold 2: They have contributors who modify the URLs in either camel case or just design their own method of casing to the modified URLs.

Here is where I am stuck. Is there ANY solution I can provide for this or is this a case in which they will need to adhere to tighter standards and hold themselves more accountable?

Thanks for the info peeps.

Comment: I would think your last suggestion. All good publications have publishing and style guidelines that should be met, so I'd say they're just going to have to meet them.

Comment: EE URLs aren't case sensitive on any site I've worked on. Is this something that only happens on IIS? Also, how did you add use an htaccess file on IIS?

Comment: @AdrianMacneil I inherited this site. The .htaccess is puzzling to me as well. It is quirky at best, but does have effect.

Comment: It might be running this: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Comment: @AdrianMacneil That was what it was. It was an older server running on Win 2000 and EE 1.6.8. They had installed HeliconTech's ASAPI Rewrite engine on that server some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpressionEngine URLs shouldn't be case sensitive (at least they aren't on any EE site I've seen, including [expressionengine.com](http://expressionengine.com/blOG)).

You should probably get to the bottom of your server issue causing URLs to be case sensitive in the first place. It might be something to do t

Comment: See your comment above for the root cause of this issue. Being I didn't have access to the server/config on this project, it was difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded Windows Server 2008 to 2019, I came across a similar situation.

I noticed that the site became "case-sensitive" for resources like images.

In the old web.config there was a configuration that was causing this situation:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

It was enough to comment the **mimeMap** tag and the resources returned to work.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <staticContent>
        <!--
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        -->
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```